# Jump into HTML tag keyboard shotcut in vscode

Tags: html, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I've spent some time looking through the docs and keyboard shortcut options and I've been unable to find this specific feature inside vscode, sublime text, or atom. It seems to obvious that I must be missing something.

What is the keyboard shortcut or name of the setting to jump into an html tag from the outside? I know the emmet plugin supports tabbing through on initial setup but if my cursor is to the right of the tag is there a shortcut to jump into the middle of the tag?

For example

is there a way to go from cursor being here

```
<label>Name</label> |
```

to here

```
<label>Name|</label>
```

without keying left 8 times?

Answer (score 1):

Try extensions like **HTML Snippets** or **HTML CSS Support**. 
It auto completes the html tags.

Or in normal case, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>
It shifts left by one word.

Answer (score 0):

VScode extensions like: **jumpy**, **Code Ace Jumper**, **MetaJump** - allow you to easily jump through code in your window.